# Haw to do the injectionParamter using Microsoft.Practices.Unity in xamrain forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, dependency-injection, unity-container

i'm developping xamarin forms app using MVVM architecture, in the beginning, i seperated the views, models, viewmodels in folders inside the PLC project. when i generate apk ,it's work fine on device or others cloud emulator. BUT, i was obligated to seperate the folders in assemblies (ViewModels, services ... ) and unsing Unity IOC injection of dependecy.

```
unityContainer = new UnityContainer();
unityContainer.RegisterType<IService, Service>();
unityContainer.RegisterType<IViewModel, ViewModel>();
```

the viewModel have a parameter
`public ViewModel(string proxy, IService service)`

so in the page.xamal.cs , i did:

`BindingContext = App.unityContainer.Resolve<ViewModel>(new ParameterOverride("proxy",proxy));`

when i launch the app on emulator it'work fine, but there is an exception on device when launching the apk
:

*System.ArgumentNullException: Parameter type inference does not work for null values.
Indicate the parameter type explicitly using a properly configured instance of the InjectionParameter or InjectionParameter classes.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution, i just add how to manage the nullable value

`BindingContext = App.unityContainer.Resolve<ViewModel>(new ParameterOverride("proxy",proxy != null ? proxy : string.Empty));`